# Sampling from an array

Tags: c#

I have a float array containing 1M floats

I want to do sampling: for each 4 floats I want to take only 1. So i am doing this :

```
for(int i = 0; i< floatArray.Length; i++) {
    if(i % 4 == 0) {
         resultFloat.Add(floatArray[i])
    }
}
```

This works fine, but it takes much time to run through all the elements , is there any other methods to make it with better results (if there are any)

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i< floatArray.Length; i+=4)`

Comment: i was think of using linq to objects but the answer is simple, work smarter not harder i guess i am dumb, but is there any chance to make it faster with linq ?

Comment: Parallel `for` may be even better.

Comment: Reserving enough capacity on `resultFloat` might help a bit as well. `resultFloats = new List<float>((floatArray.Length + 3)/4);` Or perhaps even switching to a plain array instead of a `List<T>`.

Comment: What exactly is slow here? Is it the looping through the array or creating a whole new one? Do you really need to create a new list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two factors that might be slowing down performance.

1. As you have already been offered, you should set the step to 4:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.Length; i += 4)
   {
       resultFloat.Add(floatArray[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Looks like `resultFloat` is a list of `float`. I suggest to use array instead of list, like this:

   ```
   int m = (floatArray.Length + 3) / 4;

   float[] resultFloat = new float[m];

   for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < floatArray.Length; i += 4, k++)
   {
       resultFloat[k] = floatArray[i];
   }
   ```

Comment: This might throw out of range exception, for example if `floatArray.Length` is 3.

Comment: Instead of an array you could keep it a list but set the initial size `var resultFloat = new List<float>(m);` it will then be doing the same thing behind the scenes but you can still call add.

Answer (score 6):

Just increment your loop by 4 each iteration instead of by 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i< floatArray.Length; i+=4)
{
    resultFloat.Add(floatArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have an issue with performance, then you'd be even better off not using a dynamic container for the results, but a statically sized array.

```
float[] resultFloat = new float[(floatArray.Length + 3) >> 2];
for(int i = 0; i < resultFloat.Length; i++)
    resultFloat[i] = floatArray[i << 2];
```

Usually performance isn't an issue thow, and you shouldn't optimize until a profiler gave you proof that you should. In all other cases the more readable code is preferrable.

Comment: Why did you post another answer instead of editing what you already answered? Also, you might want to explain how this works.

Comment: You have an off-by-one bug if `floatArray.Length % 4 != 0`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Since it is a fundamentally different answer and not just a refinement, posting a new one (and deleting the old one) is justified.

Comment: I stand by both answers.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert You should copy your code into a .NET Fiddle and understand that your other answer is in fact much slower than what the OP currently has.

Comment: I understand that it's slower, but I also do understand that we are talking a milliseconds difference if at all. In most cases, the gain in readability using a compact and clear Linq expression is worth more than the milliseconds saved at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option, if you want this to be the fastest, use `Parallel.For` instead of a normal for loop.

```
int resultLength = (floatArray.Length + 3) / 4;
var resultFloat = new float[resultLength];

Parallel.For(0, resultLength, i =>
{
    resultFloat[i] = floatArray[i * 4];
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
List<decimal> list = new List<decimal>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(6);
list.Add(7);
list.Add(8);
list.Add(9);
list.Add(10);
list.Add(11);
list.Add(12);
list.Add(13);
list.Add(14);
list.Add(15);
list.Add(16);

var sampleData = list.Where((x, i) => (i + 1) % (4) == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: How does this change at all the performance? Why even show how to add items to `list`?

Comment: The code is just a quick sample which I created. The main part is obviously the final linq. You can ignore the list addition. Dont think that will create much issues if pasted here. Ideally there is not much options than looping. Linq will just make it a one liner.

Comment: So, explain how that linq will be faster than a for loop. Tip: it won't.